# Identifying the issue with my File i/o code, Seg-Fault involving a Null Pointer

Tags: c, file, io, segmentation-fault

Pretty new to c in the grand scheme of things, looking for some advice on what exactly is causing the seg fault in my code. I believe it has to do with  inputf2 = fopen(argv[2], "r"); as that is the line gdb said had the issue. However i have an almost identical line earlier in my code that did not cause a seg fault for inputf1. Through looking on my own i also believe it is due to a null pointer, but i'm not quite sure how i am supposed to open a second file if not like how i have. I guess i'm just confused on file i/o in C.
The main point of my code is to read in two text files, one key, and one text body, and then encrypt the text body using the key in a Vingenere Cipher. Using i/o files in c is new to me, as usually i did that in java, so i am not quite sure why i am receiving this error. Thank you for reading! Any advice, whether it be for my question, or just syntax fixes/ other small mistakes in my code would be greatly appreciated, as i am still new and trying to refine my coding approach. Thanks again :)

GDB error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_fgets (buf=0x7ffff7ffd9f0 <_rtld_global+2448> "", n=8, fp=0x0) at iofgets.c:47
47      iofgets.c: No such file or directory.

P.S. Sorry if i did not supply enough information about the program or segfault, please ask me if any more information is needed! Also, i apologize if this isn't the place for newbie questions, just have few other options.

````
char* encrypt(char tempkeyray[512], char temptexray[512]) {
    int i, j;
    char encarr[512];

    for(i=0; i<512; i++) {
        encarr[i] = ('a' + (tempkeyray[i] + temptexray[i])%96 - 1);
    }

    for(j=0;j<512;j++) {
        printf("%c", encarr[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char textray[512] = {0}, keyray[512] = {0};
    char *temp, *temp2;
    int count = 0, count2 = 0, i, j;

    FILE *inputf1, *inputf2;
    inputf1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");


    while((fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), inputf1)) != NULL) {
        count++;
        if(isalpha(*temp)) {
            if(*temp >= 'A') { //can make more specific
                keyray[i] = tolower(*temp);
            }
            else {
                keyray[i] = *temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=count+1; i<512; i++) {
        keyray[i] = keyray[i-(count+1)];
    }

    fclose(inputf1);

    inputf2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    while((fgets(temp2, sizeof(temp2), inputf2)) != NULL) {
        count2++;
        if(isalpha(*temp2)) {
            if(*temp2 >= 'A') { //can make more specific
                textray[i] = tolower(*temp2);
            }
            else {
                textray[i] = *temp2;
            }
        }
    }
    for(j=count2; j<512; j++) {
        textray[i] = 'x';
    }

    fclose(inputf2);

    encrypt(keyray, textray);


}```
````

Comment: You have not checked `argc`, the number of program arguments. Without that, I for one won't believe that you supplied the right arguments. If you are using `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` then `argc` must be *at least* `3`.

Comment: Moreover, you *must* check that the file opened before trying to read from it. So between `fopen()` and `fgets()` you should have `if(inputf1 == NULL) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: Also the first `keyray[i]` is using the *uninitialised* variable `i` which is *undefined behaviour*. In C local variables need to be explicitly initialised, and you should be getting a compiler warning about that.

Comment: temp and temp2 are uninitialized pointers. Try declaring them as arrays, or use malloc to allocate some memory and assign them.

Comment: Raise the warning level of your compiler to the max! And then before going on with new code, handle each of the errors and warnings.